# Asus EFI BIOS beep error codes

Tags: bios

I have problems with PC based on motherboard Asus P8H67-V - 3 short beeps during startup and nothing more happens. I've tried to find the list of EFI BIOS beep codes, but without success. Can someone give advice? Link to motherboard: [here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H67V/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Asus boards have a somewhat customized Award BIOS installed, so they should conform to standard Award beep codes. Unfortunately, 3 short non-repeating is not a standard Award code, so either your motherboard doesn't have the standard Asus BIOS configuration or it's encountered an error that Award does not publish.

As an IT professional, I've always gone by a simple rule, and it's served me well: if it beeps, replace the RAM. The vast majority of BIOS beep codes occurring at boot are the result of failed or badly seated RAM. The remaining minority are the result of a failed or badly seated video card, but understand that motherboards with integrated video will rarely beep due to a video card problem, instead they will just revert to the integrated hardware. The only other real possibility is CPU trouble. Although beep codes for the failure of the motherboard itself are possible, they're not at all common, and Award publishes no such codes.

So, here's your trouble shooting steps, from my experience:

1. Reseat RAM.
2. If you have compatible spare RAM, swap it in.
3. Reseat video card (if you have one installed).
4. Reseat CPU, verify that CPU cooler makes good contact (CPUs without thermal contact to their cooler will overheat and shut off VERY fast - so fast that it will appear to be a boot failure).
5. If you have a video card installed, take it out and try the motherboard integrated. If you're using motherboard integrated, put in a spare video card if you have one.
6. Replace RAM
7. Replace CPU (I would borrow a CPU or find one by some other means to test that the CPU is the problem first, CPUs are expensive)
8. Replace motherboard.

I rank reseating the CPU a little higher than I normally would, just because of the possibility that the beeps you're hearing are the high temperature alarm and it just happens to be hitting the maximum temperature (at which point it shuts off) after around three beeps. This would be especially likely if it's not always exactly three beeps. Make sure you have some spare thermal compound to keep the CPU/cooler connection greased up.